# Sudzc for Magento web services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, magento, wsdl, sudzc

I am in very bad situation, I got the objectiveC classes from the sudzc website.
using "http://www.xxx.in/mstore/api/soap/?wsdl"

in "SDZMagentoServiceExample.m" class I get one method

[service call:self action:@selector(callHandler:) sessionId: @"" resourcePath: @"catalog_category.level" args: (id)args];

It always gives me parameter error like 
"Invalid website code requested:" if I pass dictionary or array in the args.

Please help me, I am in very bad situation.

thanks  in advance.

Comment: For the better result I updated web Magento Web service to "WS-I Compliance".

But after then I start getting below error, Any one has Idea?

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Procedure 'login' not present</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

From

```
/**
 * Catalog category api
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Api_Resource
{
```

Following code:

```
/**
 * Retrieve level of categories for category/store view/website
 *
 * @param string|int|null $website
 * @param string|int|null $store
 * @param int|null $categoryId
 * @return array
 */
public function level($website = null, $store = null, $categoryId = null)
{
```

So nor array, nor dictionary would be accepted. Only raw string or int value.

Answer (score 0):

I will not be able to help you in Objective C code, but I can show you some light with PHP. You can try out this type of call:-

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.iphone5case.in/mstore/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

/**
 * As defined in the "Manage Stores" section of Admin panel,
 * where you need to use the specific Website Code and/or Store Code
 */
$websiteCode = null;
$storeCode = 'german';

// Parent Category ID
$parentCategoryId = 2;

$firstLevel = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.level', array($websiteCode, $storeCode, $parentCategoryId));
```

Now if you print this variable "`$firstLevel`", you will get your required output, from this Web Service API.

Also whenever you are using Magento SOAP API v1, then each of the arguments will need to be as an array element. In this case, following are the main parameters expected for this API call "`category.level`":-

1. Website Code or ID
2. Store View Code or ID
3. Parent Category ID

So you need to create an array, and put sequentially each of the above arguments as array elements, like:-

```
array(
    $websiteCode,
    $storeCode,
    $parentCategoryId
)
```

Lastly, please make sure that you reference [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api) always, as you can get the usage of almost all the Web Service API methods here.

Hope it helps.